# In Visual C++, using DDE to communicate with Adobe Acrobat

Tags: pdf, dde

I'm using Visual C++ 2005.  I would like to use DDE to communicate with Adobe Acrobat, but I'm getting DDE connection failed.

Here's what I have so far:

```
HINSTANCE hRet;

/*Start the DDE server*/
hRet = ShellExecute(0, "open", "test.pdf", 0, 0, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
ASSERT((int)hRet >= 33);

/*Connect to server*/
HSZ hszApp, hszTopic;
char szApp[] = "acroview";
char szTopic[] = "control";


hszApp = DdeCreateStringHandle(dwIdInst, szApp, 0);
hszTopic = DdeCreateStringHandle(dwIdInst, szTopic, 0);

hConv = DdeConnect(dwIdInst, hszApp, hszTopic, NULL);
```

Adobe opens the pdf file fine, but when I call DdeConnect, it return NULL for hConv, telling "DDE Connection failed."  Am I missing something?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why would you use the ancient DDE instead of using the Acrobat ActiveX interfaces? DDE is Windows 3.x technology.

Comment: According to Reinhard, DDE works better than Activex. see http://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/107961-silent-pdf-print-in-adobe-reader-91/

Comment: Look here for docs http://www.adobe.com/devnet/acrobat/interapplication_communication.html

Comment: which version of Acrobat are you using? there has been a change in the DDE naming convention for Acrobat. Here is the summary:

Acroview{A|R}{MajorVersion} where {A|R} refer to Acrobat and Reader respectively.

For example, the name is AcroViewA10 for Acrobat X and AcroViewR10 for Reader 10.

Comment: Source for my above comment: http://blogs.adobe.com/pdfdevjunkie/2011/01/big-changes-in-the-dde-naming-convention-for-acrobat-x.html